# Postgres 10 and pgadmin 4 not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pgadmin-4, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-10

I installed postgres 10 and pgadmin 4 using the GUI installer provided by the enterprise db as usual i used in ubuntu 16.04. Everything getting successfully installed but nothing is working. Postgres server not getting started. Pgadmin 4 not responding when click on it. I feel like there is an incompatibility issue with newer version of them (both ubuntu and postgres). I have used ubuntu and postgres with pgadmin client for many years but never experienced such thing before.Each time i click on pgadmin 4 got an crashed message. So I installed postgres 9.6 and pgadmin 3. They worked fine. Pgadmin 4 not working even with the postgres 9.6. Any idea why?

Comment: There might be problem with EnterpriseDB installer, Have you tried pgAdmin4 python wheel?

Check the link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu

Comment: related : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081083/problem-with-qt5-while-trying-to-run-pgadmin4